# Is it possible to make a class_attribute private or protected in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class-variables, attr-accessor, class-attributes

I have a situation where I need a variable (e.g. `foo`) which is used internally within a class (e.g. `Parent`) and sub-classes (e.g. `Child`). In my case, I'm using Single Table Inheritance. `Child` should inherit the variable `foo` from `Parent` if `Child` does not set `foo`. If `Child` does set `foo`, that value should only change `foo` for `Child` but not in `Parent`. This seems like a clear cut case for [class_attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute).

The problem is that `class_attribute` is not respecting a `private` or `protected` keyword, so `foo` can be accessed from outside of `Parent` and `Child`, e.g. from the console:

```rb
# Now
Parent.foo
=> "Foo"
Child.foo
=> "Foo"/"Bar"

# What I want
Parent.foo
=> 'method_missing': protected method 'foo' called for Parent:Class (NoMethodError)
Child.foo
=> 'method_missing': protected method 'foo' called for Child:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I'm wondering how to achieve the setup I've described above, including solutions other that `class_attribute`. Note, setting `instance_accessor`, `instance_writer`, and `instance_reader` had no effect. Also note that a class instance variable will not work since `Child` will not inherit a value for `foo` from `Parent`.

```rb
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  private
  class_attribute :foo, default: "Foo" 
end

class Child < Parent
  # Child may or may not set :foo. If not, the value should be inherited from Parent.
  # Setting :foo in Child should NOT change the value of Parent, hence using class_attribute.
  # class_attribute :foo, default: "Bar"
end
```

Comment: `Child` inherits from `Parent` which inherits from `ApplicationRecord`. Are you using Single Table Inheritance?

Comment: @LesNightingill yes, I am using STI.

Answer (score 0):

I think this meets your needs, if I have understood them correctly! Take a look:

```rb
class Parent
  @@foo = "parent foo"
  class << self
    private
    def foo
      @@foo
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  @@foo = "child foo"
end

class AnotherChild < Parent
  @@foo = "another child foo"
  class << self
    def foo
      @@foo
    end
  end
end

puts Parent.foo # private
puts Parent.send(:foo) # private, but accessible via .send
puts Child.send(:foo) # inherits from Parent, => "parent foo"
puts Child.foo # private method
puts AnotherChild.foo # defined in subclass => "child foo"
```

The class attributes (@@...) are accessed via getters `def foo...`, and the getters are constrained by the `private` keyword to control the access as you expressed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I supposed in this contrived example, redefining a new class method in the child works, but I'm creating a gem and I don't think this will work in a more complicated case. Basically the user calls a `generate_methods(args)`. If they call this only in `Parent` then `Child` should inherit the generated methods. However, if `Child` calls `generate_methods(args)`, then `Child` will override `Parent` while `Parent` still keeps it's own methods. Since the class variable (`foo`) is internal to the gem, a user won't be able to do this. Thus, I wanted to use a `class_attribute`.